# Room description isn't formatted on kick page

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, kick-mute

The page that a user sees when they are kicked from chat shows the room's description, but links in the description are not clickable.  We want users who are kicked to read our rules, which are linked in the description, but this makes it more difficult for them to notice and visit the link.  Please use the same formatting for the description on this page as what is used in the sidebar.

[image: kick page with link in description circled]